Positive semidefiniteness of a Block Matrix.
Given a symmetric matrix, $$\mathbf{M} = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{A}\\ 
 \mathbf{A^T}& \mathbf{A^{T}A} 
\end{pmatrix}$$where $A$ is any $n\times n$ real matrix.

I want to show that $M$ is a positive semidefinite matrix.All I know that matrix $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is positive semidefinite if $\forall x\in R^n$,$x^TAx\ge 0$.It is quite difficult to use the above definition to prove $M$ is a positive semidefinite matrix. Is there any result for positive definiteness of a symmetric block matrix and if there is such result then kindly share that result along with the proof.I wish if some kind person show this using the basic definition.Thank you.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness
Schur's complement solves it easily since $I$ is invertible and then $A^TA-A^T A=0$
The 0 matrix is positive semi definite, so the matrix $M$ is positive semi definite.

$M=\pmatrix{I\ A^T}\pmatrix{I&A}$ is a Gram matrix. Hence it is positive semidefinite.

@DannyBlozrov What is generalized inverse of identity matrix?

@user1551 Thank you for your reply sir.

Whoever disliked the post,kindly tell the reason.

For any $x=\begin{bmatrix}u \\ w\end{bmatrix}$, direct multiplication shows that
$$\left\Vert u + Aw\right\Vert^2 =u^tu + 2u^tAw + w^tA^tAw,$$
and that
$$x^t M x = u^tu + 2u^tAw + w^tA^tAw.
$$
So $x^t M x$ is a square that is $\geq0$.

I am getting  that
$$x^t M x = u^tu + u^tAw +w^tA^tu+w^tA^tAw.
$$

$$\left\Vert u + Aw\right\Vert^2 =u^tu + u^tAw +w^tA^tu+w^tA^tAw,$$

@SandeepTiwari $u^tAw$ is a $1\times1$ scalar and thus is equal to its transpose $w^tA^tu$.

7 Got it!!Thank you.
